# How to organize a function in Python (type hints, return, flat code)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I built a simple CLI todo application. It has a function which allows to clear the todo list completely. Inside it are 5 versions of syntax. Which one do you think is the most pythonic?

```py
def purge_tasks() -> None:
    """Deletes all tasks from the todo file."""

    # Syntax 1: initial
    confirmation = input('Are you sure you want to delete all the tasks? y/n: ')
    if confirmation.lower().startswith('y'):
        tasks = get_file_data('todo.csv', only_tasks=True)
        if tasks:
            tasks.clear()
            save_data(tasks)
            print('Todo list has been cleared.')
        else:
            print('Todo list is already empty.')

    # Syntax 2: slightly flatter
    confirmation = input('Are you sure you want to delete all the tasks? y/n: ')
    if confirmation.lower().startswith('y'):
        tasks = get_file_data('todo.csv', only_tasks=True)
        if not tasks:
            print('Todo list is already empty.')
            return None
        tasks.clear()
        save_data(tasks)
        print('Todo list has been cleared.')

    # Syntax 3: flat
    confirmation = input('Are you sure you want to delete all the tasks? y/n: ')
    if not confirmation.lower().startswith('y'):
        return None
    tasks = get_file_data('todo.csv', only_tasks=True)
    if not tasks:
        print('Todo list is already empty.')
        return None
    tasks.clear()
    save_data(tasks)
    print('Todo list has been cleared.')

    # Syntax 4: doesn't print but returns either None or str
    confirmation = input('Are you sure you want to delete all the tasks? y/n: ')
    if not confirmation.lower().startswith('y'):
        return None
    tasks = get_file_data('todo.csv', only_tasks=True)
    if not tasks:
        return 'Todo list is already empty.'
    tasks.clear()
    save_data(tasks)
    return 'Todo list has been cleared.'

    # syntax 5: slightly less flat but returns only str
    confirmation = input('Are you sure you want to delete all the tasks? y/n: ')
    if confirmation.lower().startswith('y'):
        tasks = get_file_data('todo.csv', only_tasks=True)
        if not tasks:
            return 'Todo list is already empty.'
        tasks.clear()
        save_data(tasks)
        return 'Todo list has been cleared.'
```

Recently I've read about cyclomatic complexity and how it's a good practice to make your code flatter. So the issues I have are:

1. I want to use type hinting, but I don't know if returning None
   is a good practice, shouldn't I return a str (put print inside a
   message variable and return it) or just print as is and return bool
   afterwards?
2. In this particular code snippet, shouldn't I return
   False?

```py
if not confirmation.lower().startswith('y'):
   return None
```

But if I return False here shouldn't I return True down the code instead of None? Otherwise I would have to import Union to showcase that I can either return False or None and it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Anyways, what's the best way to go around it in your opinion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Patrick! In your 2nd implementation both `print('Todo list is already empty.')` and `print('Todo list has been cleared.')`  will be printed if your tasks  is empty ie when you only need `print('Todo list is already empty.')` to be printed, the same with syntax:3

Comment: Thank you. Yes I think I have patched it.

Comment: You want to move all code that modifies the task list into separate functions (or class) rather than part of the main flow. When you mix user interaction with logic code it makes it difficult to write unit tests. As to returns you don't need to use `return None` just return is fine (if you return nothing it's the same as `return None`).  I would create a task class that can load/safe tasks and has the manipulation methods on it.

Comment: That makes sense. I haven't yet learned how to do tests though but I can see how user input can get in the way. return tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the codes it is best to use this:

```
def purge_tasks(s):
    if s.lower().startswith('y'):
        tasks = get_file_data('todo.csv', only_tasks=True)
        if not tasks:
            return 'Todo list is already empty.'
        tasks.clear()
        save_data(tasks)
        return 'Todo list has been cleared.'

confirmation = input('Are you sure you want to delete all the tasks? y/n:')
print(purge_tasks(confirmation))
```